# Sample Record Generation in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I want to generate sample random records in SSIS. My expectation is to provide the no.of records and the required record layout to a program and it would generate the records accordingly.

The Row Sampling task in SSIS will not work for me since it expects an already existing record-set to select the records from.

Can this be achieved in SSIS tasks or programming thru C# and script task ? I need only the basic functionality.

Please point me to any resource online that may help me in my pursuit.

Thanks,
Raj

**Kindly let me know if additional information is neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS can do that, but you will end up coding anyways.

Many people opt for SSIS hoping to avoid coding, and to do it really quick you can use Excel http://www.uwec.edu/help/excel07/randomdata.htm
Otherwise you need to code, say in C# it can be done as posted there: [Creating Custom Data generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833244%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)